# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql

I am received a error when I run a `mysql_num_rows` query to check if a username is registered in my php files.

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
  in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\class.database.php on line 22
```

Here is my code... first is my `nameTaken` function where I run the row function...

```
public function nameTaken($username)
{
    global $database;
    if ($database->rows("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1") > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is how I connect in the database class

```
public function connect()
{
    global $config;
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($config['db']['host'], $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass']);
    mysql_select_db($config['db']['name'], $this->connection);
}
```

And here is the row function

```
public function rows($command)
{
    echo 'ROWS IS BEING CALLED BY ' . $command;
    $result = mysql_query($command);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($command);
    return $rows;
}
```

Why am I getting the error when I run a `mysql_num_rows`?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, instead use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: You want `mysql_num_rows($result)`.  However, the logic is still broken.

Comment: The function nameTaken now returns true always even if its meant to return false, any suggestions?

Comment: @user3684526 - nice try on the edit, but you have to ask a new question :) Editing questions to change the question makes a mess of the answers.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM users` - it's returning true because you have existing rows (most likely your table isn't empty). The `WHERE` clause alone should cover it. @user3684526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the result resource to `mysql_num_rows`. Change `$rows = mysql_num_rows($command);` to `$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: Thanks this fixed that error, now Its returning true even if its false can you help me with that?

Comment: the nameTaken function is by the way if you didn't know what I ment

Comment: @user3684526 - since Anthony answered your question, you should accept his answer by clicking the *Check Mark*. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Since you have another question, you should ask another question and not be a [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/173448). Its good etiquette on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have ticket it? I ticket it as soon as I found out it worked.